# Storybook template doesn't rerender on args change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, storybook

On `close` event `closeModal` method is called which changes `args.showModal` variable which controls modal's visibility:

```
import Modal from '@/components/general/Modal.vue'

export default {
    title: 'General/Modal',
    component: Modal,
    argTypes: {},
}

const Template = (args) => ({
    props: Object.keys(args),
    setup () {
        return {
            args,
        }
    },
    components: { Modal },
    methods: {
        closeModal: () => {
            args.showModal = false; // changes value, but template doesn't rerender
        }
    },
    template: `
      <Modal v-if="args.showModal" @close="closeModal">
        <template v-slot:header>
          custom header
        </template>
      </Modal>
    `,
})

export const Default = Template.bind({})
Default.args = { showModal: false }
```

My expectation was that template would be rerendered automatically when `args.showModal` changes.

If automatic rerendering is not possible in Storybook, how can I force it to rerender manually?